# Google Play show not found?

Tags: android

May I ask Question:

Because I want to import google play service, but always show error『\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.』

Is have anyone know how to solve this problem??? Extras file have install google play service[image]

Please give me some suggest, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the build target to either 13 or 11. Not sure which one  would work (I think its 11).

Close the project and Open it, this helps too.

Hope this helps.